# Morphing with Three.js

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm working on an online tool using Three.js, more precisely it's about morphing and scaling various parts of a 3d object. I enquiry if there's a way to morph an object in Three.js like this http://n-e-r-v-o-u-s.com/cellCycle/ (with the bar on the top to right) , so in a free way.

And how I can model a Mesh like a Torus but with a rectangular section and not circular. Anyone had this kind of problems? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have experience writing vertex shaders?

Comment: no, any, unfortunately. I'd like to learn more about how 3D works, I'm exploring classes of Three.js for that..

Comment: Well, I'm afraid vertex shaders is the only way I can see if you want decent speeds. You could also try to update the vertices using another geometry as reference.

Comment: Thanks, anyway when I'll find the solution I'd like to contribute to Three.js with this feature, hope so. Indeed we need a complete library, there are too many equal libraries online..
By now I think I'll just use slides to move vertices... updates soon :)

Comment: Three.js provides a way to work with shaders. Check out [ShaderMaterial](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/ShaderMaterial.js).

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking at creating procedural geometry, you can try looking at http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometries2.html

they can also be animated, checkout the code in http://jsdo.it/zz85/rVta